# Parse/Javascript - Unable to access objectID from new Objects

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm pretty new with Parse and I'm using the JS SDK.

I don't understand why I can't access the special fields of an object (objectId, createdAt, etc) when an object is created starting from parameters. But if I read the parameters it works.

Let's make an example with an object Team:

```
//here I have an array of teams
for (var i in teams) {
    var team = new Parse.Object('Team', teams[i]);
    console.log(team.get('name')); //it works
    console.log(team.get('objectId')); //it doesn't work
    console.log(team.id); //it doesn't work
    console.log(teams[i].id); //it works
}
```

I can't understand why on the new Object "team" I can access all the field but not the special ones (neither using get() or the .field notation). But it works if I navigate it like a simple object.

I mean... the source data (teams[i]) are the same!

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit: the "Team" JSON is like

```
{"name":"Real Madrid", "avatar":"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-zvPqz5WM4EE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/fh1Q0Ycpv2M/s0-c-k-no-ns/photo.jpg", "objectId":"EMUY7BoArr", "createdAt":"2015-11-17T09:31:22.614Z", "updatedAt":"2015-11-17T09:31:22.614Z"}
```

Comment: Add Team class structure in your question fir better understanding yiur problem. Parse.Object('Team') means it will create a object of Team class

Comment: what do you mean by `it doesnt work` you mean its empty and what the output for you example when you print console.log

Comment: @shareef I mean the field is undefined

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh the structure is pretty simple: 2 fields (name, avatar - both string) + the special fields of Parse (objectId, createdAt, updateAt, etc). I don't think the problem is related to the object structure

Comment: As per your comment there is another property avtar. Can you check that is working or not?

Comment: ok i took a look at https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Object.html#methods_createWithoutData but i dont have time i just wanted to give hint may be :)

Comment: I think your problem with special fielda only. That is due to some where u missed inheritense (extends).

Comment: @shareef I'm studing the whole documentation from a couple of days and I can't find the solution :(

Comment: May be your Team class is very simple but you please edit and put it here for better understanding.

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh yes... with other fields (avatar, i.e.) it works fine. I can't access only the special/default fields. What do you mean an inheritense problem? Is it wrong the way I create the "team" object starting from the parameters?

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh what do you mean the Team class? Team is a table on my parse account. Do I need to have a JS class for it?

Comment: As per documentation I think it should have a class. Can you convert team array as json.stringfy then share it in the question?

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh I added the json of a team object

Comment: Are you sure this is your exact object structure? Have you taken it as a console output or you constructed it fron your mind. If this is your exact object structure then there is no problem in your code. It should work.

Comment: Put this line and share output. Console.log (JSON.stringify (teams));

Comment: or better you can use https://jsfiddle.net/